# variable i to increment when shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

My code is displaying multiple divs with different outputs from an array, but the information that is for show is only displaying the very first entry on all outputs from i of array..

javascript-

```
    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
        const box = `
              <div class='box'>
                <h4>Away Team</h4>
                <div class="away_team"></div><br>
                <h4>Country</h4>
                <div class="competition_cluster"></div><br>
                <h4>Competition name</h4>
                <div class="competition_name"></div><br>
                <h4>Federation</h4>
                <div class="federation"></div><br>
                <h4>Home Team</h4>
                <div class="home_team"></div><br>
                <h4>Has expired?</h4>
                <div class="is_expired"></div><br>

              </div>`;


        console.dir(response);
        console.dir(response.data[1]);
        for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) { console.dir(response.data[i]); }
        for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
                
            $('body').append(box);

            $(".away_team").text(response.data[i].away_team);
            $(".competition_cluster").text(response.data[i].competition_cluster);
            $(".competition_name").text(response.data[i].competition_name);
            $(".federation").text(response.data[i].federation);
            $(".home_team").text(response.data[i].home_team);
            $(".is_expired").text(response.data[i].is_expired);


            
        }
    });
}
```

and html-

```
<body>
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Football Predictions</h1>
  </div>
  <h2> More information soon </h2>
    <button type="button" onClick="getgames()">Check info</button>
    
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

EDITED. This is the full code, can someone provide a fix?

Point is to display the information of the array that was outputted to console in body of page, but as is, the code is only repeating entries...

Comment: You're overwriting all the elements at each iteration, so only the last `i` will be shown. What're you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I'm trying to get the value of each element of array into display on each of the created divs @Terry

Comment: Are you sure each element will have `i` number of entries? You might be better of creating elements on the fly and inserting them into the DOM instead.

Comment: @Terry The number of entries per element is fixed, coming from a http request for football api, then the issue is in displaying all elements of array separatelly, I got that many divs being created, but filling them in accordingly has been a problem.. so far, got a fix?

Comment: @Terry Here, check this out, might help to understand what I want

https://timezoneft.herokuapp.com/

check console for full entries, when displayed their repeated

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML to your question. What is `box`? Can you add its initialisation code?

Comment: @trincot Here goes..

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the information there? The comment section is not the right place for that, as it has limited support for format.

Comment: @trincot did it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `box` is a container element that has elements with these "away_team", ...etc classes, you need to make sure your jQuery selectors are **local** to that latest box, as otherwise you'll keep selecting them in *all* boxes. And in that case, those `text` setters will apply to the elements in the first box only.

For that to work correctly, you should first get a reference to the box DOM element (or jQuery wrapper of it), and then pass that as second argument of the `$` selectors you have in your loop. So, in the loop body do:

```
        var $box = $(box); // Create and get the DOM element
        $('body').append($box);
        // Smaller scoped selectors:
        $(".away_team", $box).text(response.data[i].away_team);
        $(".competition_cluster", $box).text(response.data[i].competition_cluster);
        $(".competition_name", $box).text(response.data[i].competition_name);
        $(".federation", $box).text(response.data[i].federation);
        $(".home_team", $box).text(response.data[i].home_team);
        $(".is_expired", $box).text(response.data[i].is_expired);
```

Comment: Thank You!

I have an array, how do I access that array? its the odds array, its inside the initial array with all info, must I use a for loop aswell?

Comment: Yes, a nested loop.